# Loading picker from an array causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

FOUND IT! (After 6 hours).

Instead of deleting my question, I left it on in case someone else runs into the same problem.

Problem:

If I create an array with a fixed list of items

```
theArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"One", @"Two", nil];
```

and use that in a picker's `titleForRow` routine (standard wording, the only difference being the return statement):

```
return [theArray objectAtIndex: row];
```

the picker fills and works fine.

But, if I fill `theArray` using...

```
theArray = [[NSArray arrayWithArray: [textString componentsSeparatedByString: @"||"]];
```

the program bombs with a BAD ACCESS message. I have used `NSLog` to examine the `textString`, and a loop to verify that `theArray` contains the same data as if it were filled directly (including the "`nil`") but can't make the picker accept `theArray` for its row titles unless the array elements are hardwired in.

SOLUTION, add the word "`retain`": I scrapped the `arrayWithArrays` and went with:

```
theArray = [[textString componentsSeparatedByString: @"||"] retain];
```

Apparently, the array you get with `componentsSeparatedByString` is autoreleased, and doesn't stay around long enough for the picker to get populated. I'm new in the game, and not very knowledgeable about memory issues, so my explanation might not be 100%. But the program is now working.

Comment: Yep, there's a fundamental difference between the objects you get with alloc/new and those you get from other methods.  The former are retained and the latter autoreleased.  Autoreleased stuff goes "poof" whenever the UI "comes up for air".

Comment: Rob, can you please post your solution as an answer instead of adding it to the question?  That way if anyone has this problem in the future, they will know what worked.

Comment: you should post in the answer ... It would be cofusing for the user to find answer withing question (people will simply close it thinking it does not have any answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Rob Smythe's update to the question with the answer:

> SOLUTION, add the word `retain`: I scrapped the `arrayWithArrays`
>   and went with:
>
> ```
> theArray = [textString componentsSeparatedByString @"||"]retain];
> ```
>
> Apparently, the array you get with `componentsSeparatedByString` is
>   autoreleased, and doesn't stay around long enough for the picker to
>   get populated. I'm new in the game, and not very knowledgeable about
>   memory issues, so my explanation might not be 100%. But the program is
>   now working.